# Constant import to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, es6-modules

I am creating an application using the React library, but my problem is more related to JavaScript ES6 itself.

1. I have a component (page) in which I use FAB (Floating Action Button) of my own design:

```
class Page extends Component {
.
.
.
  render() {

    return (<>
      .
      .
      .
      <FloatingActionButton
        mainActionContent={<Icon.Plus size="48" />}
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({
          examinationData: null,
          modalExamination: true,
          });
        }}
        dropdown={myFAB}
      />
      .
      .
      .
    </>)
  }
}
```

2. In the main component, I store the FAB configuration in a constant

```
class Page extends Component {
.
.
.
doRefreshList() {...}
doDeleteSelected() {...}
.
.
.
render() {

  const myFAB = {
    trigger: {
      className: "m-0 rounded-circle noCaret badge-overlay",
      style: { paddingLeft: "5em", paddingRight: ".5em", zIndex: 0 },
      content: (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Icon.ThreeDotsVertical size="24" />
          {this.state.selected.length > 0 && (
            <Badge pill variant="danger">
              {this.state.selected.length}
            </Badge>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      ),
    },
    header: "Akcje",
    items: [
      {
        text: "Odśwież widok",
        icon: <Icon.ArrowRepeat size="16" />,
        onClick: () => {
          this.doRefreshList();
        },
      },
      {},
      {
        text: "Zaznacz wszystkie",
        icon: <Icon.SquareFill size="16" />,
        onClick: null,  // <-- is `null` because it is not implemented yet
      },
      {
        text: "Odznacz wszystkie",
        icon: <Icon.Square size="16" />,
        onClick: null,  
      },
      {
        text: "Odwróć zaznaczenie",
        icon: <Icon.SquareHalf size="16" />,
        onClick: null,
      },
      {},
      {
        className: "d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center",
        disabled: this.state.selected.length === 0,
        text: (
          <React.Fragment>
            <span>
              <Icon.Trash size="16" /> Usuń zaznaczone
            </span>
            {this.state.selected.length > 0 && (
              <Badge pill variant="danger">
                {this.state.selected.length}
              </Badge>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        ),
        onClick: this.doDeleteSelected,
      },
      {},
      {
        text: "Ustawienia widoku...",
        icon: <Icon.Sliders size="16" />,
        onClick: () => {
          this.setState({ modalViewOption: true });
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
  .
  .
  .
  )
}

}
```

3. However, as you can see, in this constant, I call the methods and state of the main component (page)

It's not bad because it all works nicely, but I don't like the code visually. I'd like to separate the FAB configuration - put it in a different file - and import it into the page component.
I just can't do it like this:

```
import FABConfig from 'path/to/file';

class Page extends Component {
.
.
.
  render() {
    .
    .
    .
    return (
      .
      .
      .
      <FloatingActionButton
        mainActionContent={<Icon.Plus size="48" />}
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({
          examinationData: null,
          modalExamination: true,
          });
        }}
        dropdown={FABConfig}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Of course, it will import, but it will crash - won't know what `this` is.

How can I do such an "import" of a component configuration, without messing too much in the code :D?

Comment: I corrected the code in the question a bit in terms of proper nesting of elements - it's about looking at what is located where.

Answer (score 0):

I need to admit that, you are going in a good direction with this question :)

Firstly, it is a good thing to not initialize a huge object in the render. Because on each re-render, your config object will be created from scratch. Actually, it is not so static object as you think.

Secondly, your config object contains many many dynamic contents, like this.state, some callbacks etc. If I were you, I would prefer to split this config object into some small components like:

```
const Trigger = ({length, className, style}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Icon.ThreeDotsVertical size="24" />
      {length > 0 && (
        <Badge pill variant="danger">
          {length}
        </Badge>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

and in the main component

```
<Trigger 
  length={this.state.selected.length}
  className="m-0 rounded-circle noCaret badge-overlay"
  style={{ paddingLeft: "5em", paddingRight: ".5em", zIndex: 0 }}
/>
// item usage with the same thinking,
<Item
  text="Odśwież widok"
  icon={<Icon.ArrowRepeat size="16" />}
  onClick={() => {
    this.doRefreshList();
  }}
/>
```

In this way, react can calculate when to re-render this Trigger component. With your solution, there won't be any render optimization.

In conclusion, I would prefer to create a big FAB component. In this big component, I can split `trigger`, `header`, and `item` as well because they will eventually join to render somehow but they don't know it yet. You can make them components. This is the reacty way of solving this issue :)

Comment: I like your approach, but still passes the values of `this.state` and callbacks to the "minor" components. It still doesn't allow me to export FAB component settings.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to say that you don't need to think of this data as a config. You know, a normal config should look like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html . But yours have the data for the whole rendering process. I got what you are trying to do, but this exported data should be simple JSON with static content, not a JS object with state variables and callbacks. most probably, if you insist on it, this approach will fail you in a way later.

Comment: OK, I understand what it is. I do not insist on exporting this data anymore :) I just wanted to "embellish" the code so that it would not be so long, but as I can see, sometimes it has to be like this: P (a nightmare came out ;) )
Do you have any advice on how to avoid this approach in the future? Can this be avoided at all? : D

Comment: Good to know :) It is hard to code on the comment here so I prepared an idea for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-satoshi-3muco?file=/src/App.js
You were passing some dynamic data to `<FloatingActionButton dropdown={...}/>` to build the FAB component in it, right? So, consider my answer, and let's assume that you prepared a big FAB component with small parts. Give the whole component `<FloatingActionButton />` as a prop like my codesandbox instead, rather than handling it inside `FloatingActionButton's render`. Wdyt?

Comment: You can ask, "what will I get from this solution?". In this way, your config calculation and whole data will jump into your big FAB component. So, you don't need to export or carry your data somewhere else. Another benefit is that now react can calculate what is changing and which prop is being updated for your FAB component easily. And if you continue to extend this Page and FAB component, you will see that you can easily find the line you wanted to update and manage these two components more easily in the future.

Comment: By responding to your idea. Overall, I was still wondering about such a solution https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gates-ol5l0?file=/src/App.js However, I do not know (yet) how to "code" it (I'm still learning React ;) )

As for the "What have I got?" I find that I wanted a more universal component and more efficient to implement on other pages of the project. : D Time will show how successful I have been.
Thanks for your time and conversation related to my "problem";) Good health.